# Ansible 2.6.5 unable to stop rsyslog systemd service

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, rsyslog

Goal: Stop rsyslog systemd service using ansible. The following ansible playbook executes successfully without any errors.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.6.5
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.17 (default, Jul  1 2022, 15:56:32) [GCC 7.5.0]
```

Playbook:

```
---

- name: Playbook
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Stop rsyslog
    service:
      name: rsyslog
      state: stopped
```

Expected: rsyslog service is stopped
Actual: rsyslog service is restarted

Journalctl:

```
Mar 29 13:55:04 dev systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
Mar 29 13:55:04 dev systemd[1]: Stopped System Logging Service.
Mar 29 13:55:04 dev systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Mar 29 13:55:04 dev systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
```

Comment: It looks like Ansible is successfully stopping the service, but then it's getting restarted. I wonder if it's configured with socket activation...is there an `rsyslog.socket` unit?

Comment: running `service --status-all | grep rsyslog` shows only `[ + ]  rsyslog`

Comment: That's not a useful command. If your system is using systemd, you should be using `systemctl`.  `systemctl list-units | grep syslog`. On my system, I have `syslog.socket` that automatically activates an appropriate syslog service when it is accessed.

Comment: Thanks, now I do see `syslog.socket` as well. Running `service rsyslog stop` successfully stops the service, however `systemctl stop rsyslog` acts the same as the ansible and restarts it.

Comment: You would need to stop the socket unit as well (`systemctl stop rsyslog syslog.socket`). Note that this will stop it temporarily, but both services will be active when you reboot.

Comment: Amazing, so `service` is probably stopping both units, while `systemctl` isn't. Changing the ansible playbook to first stop `syslog.socket` then stop `rsyslog` works as expected

Comment: Related: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815862